# How to change chart's color based on value (negative or positive values) in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

How to change chart's color based on value (negative or positive values) in openpyxl?
Really tough for me.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, PatternFill, Font, GradientFill,Alignment, Color, numbers
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
rows = [
['Number', 'Batch 1'],
['a', 40],
['b', -40],
['c', 50],
['d', -30],
['e', -25],
['f', 30],
]

for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)

chart = BarChart()
chartCats = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
chartData = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=7)
chart.add_data(chartData, titles_from_data = True)
chart.set_categories(chartCats)
chart.type = 'bar'
chart.style = 27
chart.height = 10
chart.width = 15
chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
chart.y_axis.number_format = '#,##0'
chart.y_axis.majorGridlines = None
sheet.add_chart(chart, 'A1')
book.save('test.xlsx')
```

The code above creates chart titled "Batch1". But I want "Batch2", in which negative and positive values show different colors.
[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?  Even any code showing the context in which you are trying to do this?

Comment: From this one (positive and negative values share the same color)
![pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRmk.png)
To this one (different colors)
![pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QURbT.png)

Comment: That's just pictures explaining your *problem*; you haven't show any effort toward a *solution*, nor any details of the code you need modified.

Comment: Sorry, first asking question on stackoverflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have revised my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently cannot be done with openpyxl. Following the instructions from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2218-excel-chart-negative-values-different-color.html I created a chart in Excel and applied a differential formatting to the data series. While openpyxl does support the `invertIfNegative` attribute for series, the original OOXML specification does not allow for additional colours for a data series. This is done using an extension to the original specification.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented with class

```
openpyxl.chart.marker.DataPoint()
```

and attribute graphicalProperties. Here is the example based on your code. The version of OpenPyXl I used is 2.5.1.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, PatternFill, Font, GradientFill,Alignment, Color, numbers
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
rows = [
['Number', 'Batch 1'],
['a', 40],
['b', -40],
['c', 50],
['d', -30],
['e', -25],
['f', 30],
]

for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)

chart = BarChart()
chartCats = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
chartData = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=7)
chart.add_data(chartData, titles_from_data = True)
chart.set_categories(chartCats)
chart.type = 'bar'
chart.style = 27
chart.height = 10
chart.width = 15
chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
chart.y_axis.number_format = '#,##0'
chart.y_axis.majorGridlines = None

series = chart.series[0]
for i in range(len(rows)-1):
    if rows[i+1][1] < 0:
        pt = openpyxl.chart.marker.DataPoint(idx=i)
        pt.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = 'A2B966'
        pt.graphicalProperties.solidFill = 'A2B966'
        series.dPt.append(pt)

sheet.add_chart(chart, 'A1')
book.save('test.xlsx')
```